# jsf inputTextarea unable to copy paste from microsoft word

Tags: jsf, textarea, copy-paste

I have an inputTextarea in my code. I am seeing some strange copy-paste behavior. If I copy text from notepad or textpad, I am able to paste it into the text area. However, if I try to do the same from a word document it fails. Any pointers on what is going on? Please see my code below:

```
<h:inputTextarea id="summary" value="#{manageProvider.provider.summary}" 
    required="true" requiredMessage="This is required" validator="myvalidator"/>
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check any input on any webpage with your browser.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "fails"? Does it paste it or does it paste an incomprehensible character sequence?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the inoput.I am unable to paste the text into the textarea. It is not junk paste, nothing gets pasted.

Comment: May be it is because of the property of the editor(Microsoft Word).That has nothing to do with your JSF code.